# Why does the DES algorithm use 16 rounds?

Tags: security, des

Can anyone tell me why the single DES (data encryption standard) algorithm uses 16 rounds?

Is there any reason to use 16 rounds other than for more security?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know specifically why the number 16 was chosen. However, one would surmise that *at that time*, cryptanalysis would have shown that 16 rounds provided an 'adequate' amount of security based on the performance tradeoff. That is to say that your "more security" statement would be correct.

Remember that less rounds means it is easier to brute-force because it takes less time and is less expensive to expand out the pipeline in dedicated hardware. More rounds on the other hand do make it harder to crack, but it is more computationally expensive across the board. This means that (especially in those days, remember DES dates back to the 1970s) it is more expensive/time-consuming - this means for the "good guys" (those who know the key and are legitimately using the cypher) too.

Therefore it is always important to find the "right balance" between performance and security. The most common guideline being "by the time the cyphertext is cracked, the value of the encrypted information has decreased to a point where it does not matter". That is, encryption will never protect data *forever* due to increasingly available computing power and diminishing costs, but it should be designed to last *long enough*.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask the designers, but the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) contains this quote:

> There have also been attacks proposed against reduced-round versions of the cipher, that is, versions of DES with fewer than 16 rounds. Such analysis gives an insight into how many rounds are needed for safety, and how much of a "security margin" the full version retains. Differential-linear cryptanalysis was proposed by Langford and Hellman in 1994, and combines differential and linear cryptanalysis into a single attack. An enhanced version of the attack can break 9-round DES with 215.8 chosen plaintexts and has a 229.2 time complexity (Biham and others, 2002).

Which suggests to me that 16 rounds was simply a tradeoff between security and performance.

The fact that 16 is a power of two could simplify things, also.